# To achieve an output from input in datastage tool

Tags: datastage

I have an input file with data

GGN,IBM
BNGLR, IBM
GGN,HCL
NOIDA,HCL
BNGLR,HCL

I want output like
IBM,GGN,BNGLR
HCL,GGN,NOIDA,BNGLR

using datastage tool.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: Do not let people guess what you want - describe it - nobody knows if your input example is one column or two for example.

Answer (score 1):

You've not given us much details to work with, so I'm making a few assumptions here on the job you're using (server/parallel) and your DataStage version. In the job design I've considered the name of the first of your columns to be "Value" and the second to be "Key".

Here is a basic job design, notice the partitioning: [Job design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly5zl.png)

Here is the first transformer setup. I know it's inneficient to add a second transformer just for a trim, but a limitation of the LastRowInGroup() function is that it can only accept columns as params. So transforms to the column it uses must be done before it's passed in the function: [first transformer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxFZh.png)

Here is the second transformer setup. The stage variable order matters, don't forget the constraint: [Second transformer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPloP.png)

In the second transformer, be sure to set the partitioning and constraint as detailed in the picture: [second transformer properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECTMT.png)

Your output data will look like this: [output stage data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srCNp.png)

Hope that helps and is clear, look through the images closely. I'm using images as they speak more than words.

Regards,
Sam Gribble
@InforgeAcademy